# Spring Boot 3. Grallvm :Native image complication. Failed to Initialize Oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to play with SpringBoot Native image compilation.

`gradle bootBuildImage` - successfully generated- the Docker Image
buBut running the docker image fails to initialize the Oracle JDBC driver. Any thoughts?

Here is the gradle build information

build.gradle plugins { id 'java' id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4' id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3' id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.27' } java { sourceCompatibility = '17' } repositories { mavenCentral() } dependencies { implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter' implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc' implementation files('lib/ojdbc8-19.3.jar') }

*Here is the console log*

```
2023-10-06T16:42:20.006Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 17 ms
2023-10-06T16:42:20.021Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] oracle.jdbc                              : Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.<init>(OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:417) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:19.3.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:249) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:171) ~[na:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:245) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:19.3.0.0.0]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.ensureInitialized(DynamicHub.java:579) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:492) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:479) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:373) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:183) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:59) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration__BeanDefinitions$Hikari.lambda$getDataSourceInstanceSupplier$1(DataSourceConfiguration__BeanDefinitions.java:50) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:68) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingBiFunction.apply(ThrowingBiFunction.java:54) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.lambda$get$2(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:202) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.invokeBeanSupplier(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:214) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:202) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RegisteredBean.resolveAutowiredArgument(RegisteredBean.java:229) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArgument(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:314) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.resolveArguments(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:260) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanInstanceSupplier.get(BeanInstanceSupplier.java:200) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveValue(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveObject(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:154) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolve(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:143) ~[na:na]
        at com.example.demo.repo.TestRepo__Autowiring.apply(TestRepo__Autowiring.java:14) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.InstanceSupplier$1.get(InstanceSupplier.java:83) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:6.0.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:3.1.4]
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: oracle.jdbc.logging.annotations.Feature.values()
        at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.Features.<init>(Features.java:52) ~[na:na]
        at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.TraceControllerImpl.<clinit>(TraceControllerImpl.java:39) ~[na:na]
        ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: oracle.jdbc.logging.annotations.Feature.values()
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1040) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Class.getMethod(DynamicHub.java:1025) ~[com.example.demo.DemoApplication:na]
        at oracle.jdbc.logging.runtime.Features.<init>(Features.java:48) ~[na:na]
        ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It is not clear what is wrong especially in your case. Please, provide `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Sounds like incompatible jars in your classpath.

Comment: Here is the build.gradle 
plugins {
 id 'java'
 id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
 id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
 id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.27'
}
java {
 sourceCompatibility = '17'
}
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
 implementation  files('lib/ojdbc8-19.3.jar')
}

Answer (score 0):

About two years ago I had a talk with the Oracle team involved in the GraalVM development (thanks to my company).

I told them the same issue, and many similar ones.

They tried including in my project a few configuration files which instructed GraalVM to don't generated native image for some JARs, like the OJDBC one.

After doing that some other similar issues have been discovered.

Their answer was: "Dor such type of projects we suggest you use the **GraalVM JVM**, without the **native image generation**, to get much better performances over the **stock JDK**, unless we will solve, in future release, those issues".

Much time has been, they worked on it for sure, but I stopped digging into **native images** by using only the **GraalVM JVM**.

The docker image I use is `ghcr.io/graalvm/jdk-community:17-ol8`.

Answer (score -2):

Replacing ojdbc8:19.3.jar with ojdbc8:21.7.0.0.jar resolved the issue. With ojdbc8:21.7.0.0.jar GraalVM successfully generated native image, and it runs with no errors.

Here is the reference document :  https://www.graalvm.org/native-image/libraries-and-frameworks/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added document reference